# How to print in new line after every 2 element

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

This is the json file:

```
{
    "x": [
        {
            "CourseCode" : "FHSC1014",
            "CourseName" : "MECHANICS"
        },
        {
            "CourseCode" : "FHCT1024",
            "CourseName" : "PROGRAMMING CONCEPT AND DESIGN"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to print it like this;

```
FHSC1014    MECHANICS
FHCT1024    PROGRAMMING CONCEPT AND DESIGN
```

This is what I tried:

```
with open("test.json", 'r+') as f: 
    data = json.load(f)
    x = data['x']
    for i in x:
        for j in i:
            print(j)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get data like this:

```
with open("test.json", 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    x = data['x']
    for i in x:
        print(i['CourseCode'], i['CourseName'])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by unpacking the values as follows:

```
import json

with open('test.json') as f:
  for d in json.load(f).get('x', []):
    print(*d.values())
```

**Output:**

```
FHSC1014 MECHANICS
FHCT1024 PROGRAMMING CONCEPT AND DESIGN
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import json

with open("test.json", 'r') as f: 
    data = json.load(f)
    x = data['x']
    for i in x:
        print(i['CourseCode'], i['CourseName'])
```

The output

```
FHSC1014 MECHANICS
FHCT1024 PROGRAMMING CONCEPT AND DESIGN
```

Answer (score -2):

looping logic can be modified like the below:

```
for i in x:
 line=""       
 for j in i:
     if len(line)>0:
        line+="\t"
     line+=i[j]
 print(line)
```